# I can run the following query in SSRS 2008 Query Designer, but the report will not run

Tags: ssrs-2008

This is the query behind the report. Notice it includes the use of a common table expression (CTE).

This code will run in query designer and in Sql Server Management Studio, however will genorate an incorrect syntax error in the IDE or when deployed.

```
-- Project System Health Report V1.0
-- Extracts a series of data points from the Draft & Reporting databases to qualify the data in a Project system
--
-- Customization
--   1. If running against Project Server 14 then search & fix "**P14**" code
--
-- Privacy/Information Protection Notes
--   1. Report contains "Proj.PROJ_NAME" - please replace with N''*** INFORMATION REDACTED ***'' to remove this information
--   2. Report contains data that can be used to quantify the amount of project work in the org, please review this for sensitivity prior to sending the data to Microsoft
-- 
-- Changelog
-- 01/05/2009 pmc Prepared for Customer Release, some perf tuning
-- 01/05/2009 pmc Changes made for Project Server 14 Alpha 
--

Declare @sqlquery1 nvarchar(max)
Declare @DraftDB nvarchar(100)
Declare @ReportingDB nvarchar(100)

-- Set DB variable to name of EPM Draft DB.
-- Set DB variable to name of EPM Reporting DB.

Set @DraftDB = N'PWA_Draft_96D2C4A4_1D9F_4C80_B3A3_82098CC6C6E5'
Set @ReportingDB = N'PWA_Reporting_96D2C4A4_1D9F_4C80_B3A3_82098CC6C6E5'

set @sqlquery1 = N'use [' + @DraftDB + N']; 
-- Common Table Expression to Recursively Parse Project Hierarchy
WITH ProjHierarchy
AS (SELECT Proj.PARENT_PROJ_UID, 1 AS DEPTH
    FROM dbo.MSP_PROJ_HIERARCHIES AS Proj
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Proj.PARENT_PROJ_UID, Hier.DEPTH+1
    FROM dbo.MSP_PROJ_HIERARCHIES AS Proj
    INNER JOIN ProjHierarchy AS Hier
    ON Proj.CHILD_PROJ_UID = Hier.PARENT_PROJ_UID) 
SELECT Proj.PROJ_UID 
       ,Proj.PROJ_NAME AS N''Project Name'' -- If sensitive uncomment below and comment this line
       --, N''*** INFORMATION REDACTED ***'' AS N''Project Name''
       ,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(23), Proj.PROJ_INFO_START_DATE,20) AS N''Project Start Date''
       ,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(23), Proj.PROJ_INFO_FINISH_DATE,20) AS N''Project Finish Date''
       ,DATEDIFF(mm, Proj.PROJ_INFO_START_DATE,Proj.PROJ_INFO_FINISH_DATE) AS N''Project Length (Months)''
       ,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(23), Proj.CREATED_DATE,20) AS N''Project Created''
       ,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(23), Proj.WPROJ_LAST_PUB,20) AS N''Project Published''
       ,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(23), Proj.MOD_DATE,20) AS N''Project Modified''
       ,CASE ISNULL(Proj.WPROJ_STS_SUBWEB_NAME,N'''') WHEN N'''' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS N''Workspace''
       ,CASE ISNULL(Proj.PROJ_SESSION_UID,N''00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'') 
        WHEN N''00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'' 
        THEN 0 ELSE DATEDIFF(d,Proj.PROJ_CHECKOUTDATE,getdate()) END AS N''Checked Out (Days)''
       ,CAST(Task.TASK_ACT_WORK / 60000 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS N''Project Total Actual Work (Hrs)''
       ,CAST(Task.TASK_REM_WORK / 60000 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS N''Project Total Remaining Work (Hrs)''
       ,ISNULL(ProjCF.[Number of Project Custom Field Values],0) AS N''Number of Project Custom Field Values''
       ,ISNULL(ProjLCF.[Number of Local Custom Field Definitions],0) AS N''Number of Local Custom Field Definitions''
       ,ISNULL(HierSummaryData.[Number of SubProjects],0) AS N''Number of SubProjects''
       ,ISNULL(HierSummaryData.[SubProject Depth],0) AS N''SubProject Depth''
       ,ISNULL(LeafTaskData.[Leaf Task Count],0) AS N''Leaf Task Count''
       ,ISNULL(LeafTaskData.[Max Leaf Calendar Duration (Days)], 0) AS N''Max Leaf Task Calendar Duration (Days)''
       ,ISNULL(LeafTaskData.[Average Leaf Calendar Duration (Days)], 0) AS N''Average Leaf Task Calendar Duration (Days)''
       ,ISNULL(LeafTaskData.[Total Leaf Task Ignoring ResCalendar], 0) AS N''Total Leaf Task Ignoring ResCalendar''
       ,ISNULL(AllTaskData.[Task Count],0) AS N''Total Task Count''
       ,ISNULL(RecentTasks.[Recent Changes],0) AS N''Total Recent Changed''
       ,ISNULL(LinkData.[Total Number of Links],0) AS N''Total Number of Links''
       ,ISNULL(LinkData.[Cross Project Links],0) AS N''Cross Project Links''
       ,ISNULL(TaskCFAggregated.[Max Task Custom Fields],0) AS N''Max Task Custom Fields''
       ,ISNULL(TaskCFAggregated.[Average Task Custom Fields],0) AS N''Average Task Custom Fields''
       ,ISNULL(TaskCFAggregated.[Total Task Custom Fields],0) AS N''Total Task Custom Fields''
       ,ISNULL(TaskCFAggregated.[Number of Tasks with Custom Fields],0) AS N''Number of Tasks with Custom Fields''
       ,ISNULL(AssnDataAggregated.[Average Resources on Assigned Tasks],0) AS N''Average Resources on Assigned Tasks''
       ,ISNULL(AssnDataAggregated.[Total Number of Assignments],0) AS N''Total Number of Assignments''
       ,ISNULL(AssnDataAggregated.[Number of Tasks with Assignments],0) AS N''Number of Tasks with Assignments''
       ,ISNULL(RealData.[Actual Count],0) AS N''Actual Count in AssnByDay Table''
       ,ISNULL(AssnCFAggregated.[Max Assn Custom Fields],0) AS N''Max Assn Custom Fields''
       ,ISNULL(AssnCFAggregated.[Average Assn Custom Fields],0) AS N''Average Assn Custom Fields''
       ,ISNULL(AssnCFAggregated.[Total Assn Custom Fields],0) AS N''Total Assn Custom Fields''
       ,ISNULL(AssnCFAggregated.[Number of Assn with Custom Fields],0) AS N''Number of Assn with Custom Fields''  
       ,ISNULL(TaskBaseAggregated.[Number of Baselines],0) AS N''Number of Baselines''
       ,ISNULL(TaskBaseAggregated.[Total Task Baseline Rows],0) AS N''Total Task Baseline Rows''
       ,ISNULL(AssnBaseAggregated.[Total Assn Baseline Rows],0) AS N''Total Assn Baseline Rows''  
       ,ISNULL(ResBaseAggregated.[Total Resource Baseline Rows],0) AS N''Total Resource Baseline Rows''
       ,ISNULL(Resources.[Total Resources],0) AS N''Project Team (All)''
       ,ISNULL(Resources.[Enterprise Resources],0) AS N''Project Team (Enterprise)''
       ,ISNULL(ActiveResAggregated.[Active Resources],0) AS N''Active Resources''
       ,getdate() as [Date/Time of Recording]
FROM dbo.MSP_PROJECTS AS Proj WITH(NOLOCK)
-- Project Summary Task
INNER JOIN dbo.MSP_TASKS AS Task WITH(NOLOCK)
ON (Proj.PROJ_UID = Task.PROJ_UID AND Task.TASK_OPTINDX = 1) -- Use the Project Summary Task for rollup values
-- Get the rowcount from our (usually) largest table 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Assn.ProjectUID as N''PROJ_UID''
                       ,COUNT(*) + 1 AS N''Actual Count''
                 FROM [' + @ReportingDB + ']..MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay AS Assn
                 GROUP BY Assn.ProjectUID) AS RealData
ON (Proj.PROJ_UID = RealData.PROJ_UID)
-- Project Custom Field Data
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT pcf.PROJ_UID
                       ,COUNT(*) AS N''Number of Project Custom Field Values''
                 FROM dbo.MSP_PROJ_CUSTOM_FIELD_VALUES AS pcf WITH(NOLOCK)
                 GROUP BY pcf.PROJ_UID) AS ProjCF
ON (Proj.PROJ_UID = ProjCF.PROJ_UID)
-- Project Local Custom Fields
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT plcf.PROJ_UID
                       ,COUNT(*) AS N''Number of Local Custom Field Definitions''
                 FROM dbo.MSP_PROJECT_CUSTOM_FIELDS AS plcf WITH(NOLOCK)
                 GROUP BY plcf.PROJ_UID) AS ProjLCF
ON (Proj.PROJ_UID = ProjLCF.PROJ_UID)'

set @sqlquery1 = @sqlquery1 + '                 
-- Project Hierarchy Below each Project
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT HierData.PROJ_UID
                       ,COUNT(HierData.DEPTH) AS N''Number of SubProjects''
                       ,MAX(HierData.DEPTH) AS N''SubProject Depth''
                 FROM (SELECT Proj.PROJ_UID
                             ,Hier.DEPTH 
                       FROM ProjHierarchy as Hier
                       INNER JOIN dbo.MSP_PROJECTS AS Proj WITH(NOLOCK)
                       ON Hier.PARENT_PROJ_UID = Proj.PROJ_UID) AS HierData
                 GROUP BY HierData.PROJ_UID) AS HierSummaryData
ON (Proj.PROJ_UID = HierSummaryData.PROJ_UID)
-- Project resource data
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Pres.PROJ_UID
                       ,COUNT(*) AS N''Total Resources''
                       ,SUM(CAST(Pres.RES_IS_ENTERPRISE_RESOURCE AS INT)) AS N''Enterprise Resources''
                       ,SUM(CAST(Pres.RES_BOOKING_TYPE AS INT)/2) AS N''Proposed Resources''
                 FROM dbo.MSP_PROJECT_RESOURCES AS Pres WITH(NOLOCK)
                 WHERE Pres.RES_ID > 0 -- Ignore internal resources
                 GROUP BY Pres.PROJ_UID) AS Resources
ON (Proj.PROJ_UID = Resources.PROJ_UID)
 -- Resources with Assignments
 LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT ActiveRes.PROJ_UID
                        ,COUNT(*) AS N''Active Resources''
                  FROM (SELECT Assn.PROJ_UID
                              ,Assn.RES_UID
                        FROM dbo.MSP_ASSIGNMENTS AS Assn WITH(NOLOCK)
                        INNER JOIN dbo.MSP_PROJECT_RESOURCES AS Pres WITH(NOLOCK)
                        ON (Assn.PROJ_UID = Pres.PROJ_UID AND Assn.RES_UID = Pres.RES_UID)
                        WHERE Pres.RES_ID > 0 -- Ignore internal resources
                        GROUP BY Assn.PROJ_UID, Assn.RES_UID) AS ActiveRes
                  GROUP BY ActiveRes.PROJ_UID) AS ActiveResAggregated
 ON (Proj.PROJ_UID = ActiveResAggregated.PROJ_UID)  
-- Leaf task data            
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Task.PROJ_UID
                   ,COUNT(*) AS N''Leaf Task Count''
                   -- Implementation Note - Use _SCHED_ below for P14, Ignores User Scheduled dates 
                   ,MAX(DATEDIFF(d,Task.TASK_START_DATE, Task.TASK_FINISH_DATE)) AS N''Max Leaf Calendar Duration (Days)''
                   ,AVG(DATEDIFF(d,Task.TASK_START_DATE, Task.TASK_FINISH_DATE)) AS N''Average Leaf Calendar Duration (Days)''
                   --**P14**: ,MAX(DATEDIFF(d,Task.TASK_SCHED_START, Task.TASK_SCHED_FINISH)) AS N''Max Calendar Duration (Days)''
                   --**P14**: ,AVG(DATEDIFF(d,Task.TASK_SCHED_START, Task.TASK_SCHED_FINISH)) AS N''Average Calendar Duration (Days)''
                   ,SUM(CAST(TASK_IGNORES_RES_CAL AS INT)) AS N''Total Leaf Task Ignoring ResCalendar''
                 FROM dbo.MSP_TASKS AS Task WITH(NOLOCK)
                 WHERE Task.TASK_IS_SUMMARY = 0x0 -- Ignore summary tasks
                 AND Task.TASK_IS_MILESTONE = 0x0 -- Ignore milestones
                 AND Task.TASK_IS_SUBPROJ = 0x0 -- Ignore subprojects
                 GROUP BY Task.PROJ_UID) AS LeafTaskData
ON (Proj.PROJ_UID = LeafTaskData.PROJ_UID)
-- All visible tasks in the project
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Task.PROJ_UID
                   ,COUNT(*) AS N''Task Count''
                 FROM dbo.MSP_TASKS AS Task WITH(NOLOCK)
                 WHERE Task.TASK_OPTINDX > 1
                 GROUP BY Task.PROJ_UID) AS AllTaskData
ON (Proj.PROJ_UID = AllTaskData.PROJ_UID)
-- Task data changed on Last Project saved
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Task.PROJ_UID
                       ,COUNT(*) AS N''Recent Changes''
                 FROM dbo.MSP_TASKS AS Task WITH(NOLOCK)
                 INNER JOIN dbo.MSP_PROJECTS AS Proj WITH(NOLOCK)
                 ON (Task.PROJ_UID = Proj.PROJ_UID AND Task.MOD_REV_COUNTER = Proj.MOD_REV_COUNTER)
                 WHERE Task.TASK_OPTINDX > 1
                 GROUP BY Task.PROJ_UID) AS RecentTasks
ON (Proj.PROJ_UID = RecentTasks.PROJ_UID)
-- Task Custom Field Data
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT TaskCF.PROJ_UID
                       ,MAX(TaskCF.[Task CF Count]) AS N''Max Task Custom Fields''
                       ,AVG(TaskCF.[Task CF Count]) AS N''Average Task Custom Fields''
                       ,SUM(TaskCF.[Task CF Count]) AS N''Total Task Custom Fields''
                       ,COUNT(*) AS N''Number of Tasks with Custom Fields''
                 FROM (SELECT TCF.PROJ_UID
                             ,TCF.TASK_UID
                             ,COUNT(*) AS N''Task CF Count''
                       FROM dbo.MSP_TASK_CUSTOM_FIELD_VALUES AS TCF WITH(NOLOCK)
                       GROUP BY TCF.PROJ_UID, TCF.TASK_UID) AS TaskCF
                 GROUP BY TaskCF.PROJ_UID) AS TaskCFAggregated
ON (Proj.PROJ_UID = TaskCFAggregated.PROJ_UID)
-- Link Data
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Links.PROJ_UID
                       ,COUNT(*) AS N''Total Number of Links''
                       ,SUM(CAST(LINK_IS_CROSS_PROJ AS INT)) AS N''Cross Project Links''
                 FROM dbo.MSP_LINKS AS Links
                 GROUP BY Links.PROJ_UID) AS LinkData
ON (Proj.PROJ_UID = LinkData.PROJ_UID)
-- Task Baseline Data
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT TaskBaseData.PROJ_UID
                       ,COUNT(*) AS N''Number of Baselines''
                       ,SUM(TaskbaseData.[Task Baseline Rows]) AS N''Total Task Baseline Rows''
                 FROM (SELECT TaskBase.PROJ_UID
                             ,TaskBase.TB_BASE_NUM AS N''Baseline''
                             ,COUNT(*) AS N''Task Baseline Rows''
                       FROM dbo.MSP_TASK_BASELINES AS TaskBase WITH(NOLOCK)
                       GROUP BY TaskBase.PROJ_UID, TaskBase.TB_BASE_NUM) AS TaskBaseData
                 GROUP BY TaskBaseData.PROJ_UID) AS TaskBaseAggregated
ON (Proj.PROJ_UID = TaskBaseAggregated.PROJ_UID)
-- Assignment Baseline Data
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT AssnBaseData.PROJ_UID
                       ,COUNT(*) AS N''Total Assn Baseline Rows''
                 FROM dbo.MSP_ASSIGNMENT_BASELINES AS AssnBaseData WITH(NOLOCK)
                 GROUP BY AssnBaseData.PROJ_UID) AS AssnBaseAggregated
ON (Proj.PROJ_UID = AssnBaseAggregated.PROJ_UID)
-- Resource Baseline Data
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT ResBaseData.PROJ_UID
                       ,COUNT(*) AS N''Total Resource Baseline Rows''
                 FROM dbo.MSP_PROJECT_RESOURCE_BASELINES AS ResBaseData WITH(NOLOCK)
                 GROUP BY ResBaseData.PROJ_UID) AS ResBaseAggregated
ON (Proj.PROJ_UID = ResBaseAggregated.PROJ_UID) 
-- Assignment Data Summary
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT AssnTaskData.PROJ_UID
                       ,AVG(AssnTaskData.[Assignment Count]) AS N''Average Resources on Assigned Tasks''
                       ,SUM(AssnTaskData.[Assignment Count]) AS N''Total Number of Assignments''
                       ,COUNT(*) AS N''Number of Tasks with Assignments''
                 FROM (SELECT Assn.PROJ_UID
                             ,Assn.TASK_UID
                             ,COUNT(*) AS N''Assignment Count''
                       FROM dbo.MSP_ASSIGNMENTS AS Assn WITH(NOLOCK)
                       GROUP BY Assn.PROJ_UID, Assn.TASK_UID) AS AssnTaskData
                 GROUP BY AssnTaskData.PROJ_UID) AS AssnDataAggregated    
 ON (Proj.PROJ_UID = AssnDataAggregated.PROJ_UID)
-- Assignment Custom Field Data
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT AssnCF.PROJ_UID
                       ,MAX(AssnCF.[Assn CF Count]) AS N''Max Assn Custom Fields''
                       ,AVG(AssnCF.[Assn CF Count]) AS N''Average Assn Custom Fields''
                       ,SUM(AssnCF.[Assn CF Count]) AS N''Total Assn Custom Fields''
                       ,COUNT(*) AS N''Number of Assn with Custom Fields''
                 FROM (SELECT ACF.PROJ_UID
                             ,ACF.ASSN_UID
                             ,COUNT(*) AS N''Assn CF Count''
                       FROM dbo.MSP_ASSN_CUSTOM_FIELD_VALUES AS ACF WITH(NOLOCK)
                       GROUP BY ACF.PROJ_UID, ACF.ASSN_UID) AS AssnCF
                 GROUP BY AssnCF.PROJ_UID) AS AssnCFAggregated
ON (Proj.PROJ_UID = AssnCFAggregated.PROJ_UID);'

exec (@sqlquery1)
```

Comment: Ive had error messages in the query designer window also when using with CTE statements however my reports would still run. You query is far more complex than mine. Is there no way you can store this query in a view and do a simple select statement on the view?

Answer (score 0):

All I can suggest you do is trim your query down to nothing, then add elements until you find the offending bit of code.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the query to work in both query designer, and the report, by not using the EXEC() command. I also changed the ‘’ in the query.

```
-- Project System Health Report V1.0
-- Extracts a series of data points from the Archive & Reporting databases to qualify the data in a Project system
--
-- Customization
--   1. If running against Project Server 14 then search & fix "**P14**" code
--
-- Privacy/Information Protection Notes
--   1. Report contains "Proj.PROJ_NAME" - please replace with N''*** INFORMATION REDACTED ***'' to remove this information
--   2. Report contains data that can be used to quantify the amount of project work in the org, please review this for sensitivity prior to sending the data to Microsoft
-- 
-- Changelog
-- 01/05/2009 pmc Prepared for Customer Release, some perf tuning
-- 01/05/2009 pmc Changes made for Project Server 14 Alpha 
--

-- Common Table Expression to Recursively Parse Project Hierarchy
-- Declare @ReportingDB nvarchar(100)
-- Set @ReportingDB = 'PWA_Reporting_96D2C4A4_1D9F_4C80_B3A3_82098CC6C6E5'

;WITH ProjHierarchy
AS (SELECT Proj.PARENT_PROJ_UID, 1 AS DEPTH
    FROM dbo.MSP_PROJ_HIERARCHIES AS Proj
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Proj.PARENT_PROJ_UID, Hier.DEPTH+1
    FROM dbo.MSP_PROJ_HIERARCHIES AS Proj
    INNER JOIN ProjHierarchy AS Hier
    ON Proj.CHILD_PROJ_UID = Hier.PARENT_PROJ_UID) 
SELECT Proj.PROJ_UID 
       ,Proj.PROJ_NAME AS 'Project Name' -- If sensitive uncomment below and comment this line
       --, N''*** INFORMATION REDACTED ***'' AS N''Project Name''
       ,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(23), Proj.PROJ_INFO_START_DATE,20) AS 'Project Start Date'
       ,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(23), Proj.PROJ_INFO_FINISH_DATE,20) AS 'Project Finish Date'
       ,DATEDIFF(mm, Proj.PROJ_INFO_START_DATE,Proj.PROJ_INFO_FINISH_DATE) AS 'Project Length (Months)'
       ,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(23), Proj.CREATED_DATE,20) AS 'Project Created'
       ,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(23), Proj.WPROJ_LAST_PUB,20) AS 'Project Published'
       ,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(23), Proj.MOD_DATE,20) AS 'Project Modified'
       ,CASE ISNULL(Proj.WPROJ_STS_SUBWEB_NAME,'') WHEN '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS 'Workspace'
       ,CASE ISNULL(Proj.PROJ_SESSION_UID,'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000') 
        WHEN '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' 
        THEN 0 ELSE DATEDIFF(d,Proj.PROJ_CHECKOUTDATE,getdate()) END AS 'Checked Out (Days)'
       ,CAST(Task.TASK_ACT_WORK / 60000 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS 'Project Total Actual Work (Hrs)'
       ,CAST(Task.TASK_REM_WORK / 60000 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS 'Project Total Remaining Work (Hrs)'
       ,ISNULL(ProjCF.[Number of Project Custom Field Values],0) AS 'Number of Project Custom Field Values'
       ,ISNULL(ProjLCF.[Number of Local Custom Field Definitions],0) AS 'Number of Local Custom Field Definitions'
       ,ISNULL(HierSummaryData.[Number of SubProjects],0) AS 'Number of SubProjects'
       ,ISNULL(HierSummaryData.[SubProject Depth],0) AS 'SubProject Depth'
       ,ISNULL(LeafTaskData.[Leaf Task Count],0) AS 'Leaf Task Count'
       ,ISNULL(LeafTaskData.[Max Leaf Calendar Duration (Days)], 0) AS 'Max Leaf Task Calendar Duration (Days)'
       ,ISNULL(LeafTaskData.[Average Leaf Calendar Duration (Days)], 0) AS 'Average Leaf Task Calendar Duration (Days)'
       ,ISNULL(LeafTaskData.[Total Leaf Task Ignoring ResCalendar], 0) AS 'Total Leaf Task Ignoring ResCalendar'
       ,ISNULL(AllTaskData.[Task Count],0) AS 'Total Task Count'
       ,ISNULL(RecentTasks.[Recent Changes],0) AS 'Total Recent Changed'
       ,ISNULL(LinkData.[Total Number of Links],0) AS 'Total Number of Links'
       ,ISNULL(LinkData.[Cross Project Links],0) AS 'Cross Project Links'
       ,ISNULL(TaskCFAggregated.[Max Task Custom Fields],0) AS 'Max Task Custom Fields'
       ,ISNULL(TaskCFAggregated.[Average Task Custom Fields],0) AS 'Average Task Custom Fields'
       ,ISNULL(TaskCFAggregated.[Total Task Custom Fields],0) AS 'Total Task Custom Fields'
       ,ISNULL(TaskCFAggregated.[Number of Tasks with Custom Fields],0) AS 'Number of Tasks with Custom Fields'
       ,ISNULL(AssnDataAggregated.[Average Resources on Assigned Tasks],0) AS 'Average Resources on Assigned Tasks'
       ,ISNULL(AssnDataAggregated.[Total Number of Assignments],0) AS 'Total Number of Assignments'
       ,ISNULL(AssnDataAggregated.[Number of Tasks with Assignments],0) AS 'Number of Tasks with Assignments'
       ,ISNULL(RealData.[Actual Count],0) AS 'Actual Count in AssnByDay Table'
       ,ISNULL(AssnCFAggregated.[Max Assn Custom Fields],0) AS 'Max Assn Custom Fields'
       ,ISNULL(AssnCFAggregated.[Average Assn Custom Fields],0) AS 'Average Assn Custom Fields'
       ,ISNULL(AssnCFAggregated.[Total Assn Custom Fields],0) AS 'Total Assn Custom Fields'
       ,ISNULL(AssnCFAggregated.[Number of Assn with Custom Fields],0) AS 'Number of Assn with Custom Fields' 
       ,ISNULL(TaskBaseAggregated.[Number of Baselines],0) AS 'Number of Baselines'
       ,ISNULL(TaskBaseAggregated.[Total Task Baseline Rows],0) AS 'Total Task Baseline Rows'
       ,ISNULL(AssnBaseAggregated.[Total Assn Baseline Rows],0) AS 'Total Assn Baseline Rows' 
       ,ISNULL(ResBaseAggregated.[Total Resource Baseline Rows],0) AS 'Total Resource Baseline Rows'
       ,ISNULL(Resources.[Total Resources],0) AS 'Project Team (All)'
       ,ISNULL(Resources.[Enterprise Resources],0) AS 'Project Team (Enterprise)'
       ,ISNULL(ActiveResAggregated.[Active Resources],0) AS 'Active Resources'
       ,getdate() as [Date/Time of Recording]
FROM dbo.MSP_PROJECTS AS Proj WITH(NOLOCK)
-- Project Summary Task
INNER JOIN dbo.MSP_TASKS AS Task WITH(NOLOCK)
ON (Proj.PROJ_UID = Task.PROJ_UID AND Task.TASK_OPTINDX = 1) -- Use the Project Summary Task for rollup values
-- Get the rowcount from our (usually) largest table 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Assn.ProjectUID as 'PROJ_UID'
                       ,COUNT(*) + 1 AS 'Actual Count'
                 FROM PWA_Reporting_96D2C4A4_1D9F_4C80_B3A3_82098CC6C6E5..MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay AS Assn
                 GROUP BY Assn.ProjectUID) AS RealData
ON (Proj.PROJ_UID = RealData.PROJ_UID)
-- Project Custom Field Data
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT pcf.PROJ_UID
                       ,COUNT(*) AS 'Number of Project Custom Field Values'
                 FROM dbo.MSP_PROJ_CUSTOM_FIELD_VALUES AS pcf WITH(NOLOCK)
                 GROUP BY pcf.PROJ_UID) AS ProjCF
ON (Proj.PROJ_UID = ProjCF.PROJ_UID)
-- Project Local Custom Fields
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT plcf.PROJ_UID
                       ,COUNT(*) AS 'Number of Local Custom Field Definitions'
                 FROM dbo.MSP_PROJECT_CUSTOM_FIELDS AS plcf WITH(NOLOCK)
                 GROUP BY plcf.PROJ_UID) AS ProjLCF
ON (Proj.PROJ_UID = ProjLCF.PROJ_UID)

-- Project Hierarchy Below each Project
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT HierData.PROJ_UID
                       ,COUNT(HierData.DEPTH) AS 'Number of SubProjects'
                       ,MAX(HierData.DEPTH) AS 'SubProject Depth'
                 FROM (SELECT Proj.PROJ_UID
                             ,Hier.DEPTH 
                       FROM ProjHierarchy as Hier
                       INNER JOIN dbo.MSP_PROJECTS AS Proj WITH(NOLOCK)
                       ON Hier.PARENT_PROJ_UID = Proj.PROJ_UID) AS HierData
                 GROUP BY HierData.PROJ_UID) AS HierSummaryData
ON (Proj.PROJ_UID = HierSummaryData.PROJ_UID)
-- Project resource data
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Pres.PROJ_UID
                       ,COUNT(*) AS 'Total Resources'
                       ,SUM(CAST(Pres.RES_IS_ENTERPRISE_RESOURCE AS INT)) AS 'Enterprise Resources'
                       ,SUM(CAST(Pres.RES_BOOKING_TYPE AS INT)/2) AS 'Proposed Resources'
                 FROM dbo.MSP_PROJECT_RESOURCES AS Pres WITH(NOLOCK)
                 WHERE Pres.RES_ID > 0 -- Ignore internal resources
                 GROUP BY Pres.PROJ_UID) AS Resources
ON (Proj.PROJ_UID = Resources.PROJ_UID)
 -- Resources with Assignments
 LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT ActiveRes.PROJ_UID
                        ,COUNT(*) AS 'Active Resources'
                  FROM (SELECT Assn.PROJ_UID
                              ,Assn.RES_UID
                        FROM dbo.MSP_ASSIGNMENTS AS Assn WITH(NOLOCK)
                        INNER JOIN dbo.MSP_PROJECT_RESOURCES AS Pres WITH(NOLOCK)
                        ON (Assn.PROJ_UID = Pres.PROJ_UID AND Assn.RES_UID = Pres.RES_UID)
                        WHERE Pres.RES_ID > 0 -- Ignore internal resources
                        GROUP BY Assn.PROJ_UID, Assn.RES_UID) AS ActiveRes
                  GROUP BY ActiveRes.PROJ_UID) AS ActiveResAggregated
 ON (Proj.PROJ_UID = ActiveResAggregated.PROJ_UID)  
-- Leaf task data            
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Task.PROJ_UID
                   ,COUNT(*) AS 'Leaf Task Count'
                   -- Implementation Note - Use _SCHED_ below for P14, Ignores User Scheduled dates 
                   ,MAX(DATEDIFF(d,Task.TASK_START_DATE, Task.TASK_FINISH_DATE)) AS 'Max Leaf Calendar Duration (Days)'
                   ,AVG(DATEDIFF(d,Task.TASK_START_DATE, Task.TASK_FINISH_DATE)) AS 'Average Leaf Calendar Duration (Days)'
                   --**P14**: ,MAX(DATEDIFF(d,Task.TASK_SCHED_START, Task.TASK_SCHED_FINISH)) AS N''Max Calendar Duration (Days)''
                   --**P14**: ,AVG(DATEDIFF(d,Task.TASK_SCHED_START, Task.TASK_SCHED_FINISH)) AS N''Average Calendar Duration (Days)''
                   ,SUM(CAST(TASK_IGNORES_RES_CAL AS INT)) AS 'Total Leaf Task Ignoring ResCalendar'
                 FROM dbo.MSP_TASKS AS Task WITH(NOLOCK)
                 WHERE Task.TASK_IS_SUMMARY = 0x0 -- Ignore summary tasks
                 AND Task.TASK_IS_MILESTONE = 0x0 -- Ignore milestones
                 AND Task.TASK_IS_SUBPROJ = 0x0 -- Ignore subprojects
                 GROUP BY Task.PROJ_UID) AS LeafTaskData
ON (Proj.PROJ_UID = LeafTaskData.PROJ_UID)
-- All visible tasks in the project
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Task.PROJ_UID
                   ,COUNT(*) AS 'Task Count'
                 FROM dbo.MSP_TASKS AS Task WITH(NOLOCK)
                 WHERE Task.TASK_OPTINDX > 1
                 GROUP BY Task.PROJ_UID) AS AllTaskData
ON (Proj.PROJ_UID = AllTaskData.PROJ_UID)
-- Task data changed on Last Project saved
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Task.PROJ_UID
                       ,COUNT(*) AS N'Recent Changes'
                 FROM dbo.MSP_TASKS AS Task WITH(NOLOCK)
                 INNER JOIN dbo.MSP_PROJECTS AS Proj WITH(NOLOCK)
                 ON (Task.PROJ_UID = Proj.PROJ_UID AND Task.MOD_REV_COUNTER = Proj.MOD_REV_COUNTER)
                 WHERE Task.TASK_OPTINDX > 1
                 GROUP BY Task.PROJ_UID) AS RecentTasks
ON (Proj.PROJ_UID = RecentTasks.PROJ_UID)
-- Task Custom Field Data
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT TaskCF.PROJ_UID
                       ,MAX(TaskCF.[Task CF Count]) AS 'Max Task Custom Fields'
                       ,AVG(TaskCF.[Task CF Count]) AS 'Average Task Custom Fields'
                       ,SUM(TaskCF.[Task CF Count]) AS 'Total Task Custom Fields'
                       ,COUNT(*) AS 'Number of Tasks with Custom Fields'
                 FROM (SELECT TCF.PROJ_UID
                             ,TCF.TASK_UID
                             ,COUNT(*) AS 'Task CF Count'
                       FROM dbo.MSP_TASK_CUSTOM_FIELD_VALUES AS TCF WITH(NOLOCK)
                       GROUP BY TCF.PROJ_UID, TCF.TASK_UID) AS TaskCF
                 GROUP BY TaskCF.PROJ_UID) AS TaskCFAggregated
ON (Proj.PROJ_UID = TaskCFAggregated.PROJ_UID)
-- Link Data
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Links.PROJ_UID
                       ,COUNT(*) AS 'Total Number of Links'
                       ,SUM(CAST(LINK_IS_CROSS_PROJ AS INT)) AS 'Cross Project Links'
                 FROM dbo.MSP_LINKS AS Links
                 GROUP BY Links.PROJ_UID) AS LinkData
ON (Proj.PROJ_UID = LinkData.PROJ_UID)
-- Task Baseline Data
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT TaskBaseData.PROJ_UID
                       ,COUNT(*) AS 'Number of Baselines'
                       ,SUM(TaskbaseData.[Task Baseline Rows]) AS 'Total Task Baseline Rows'
                 FROM (SELECT TaskBase.PROJ_UID
                             ,TaskBase.TB_BASE_NUM AS 'Baseline'
                             ,COUNT(*) AS 'Task Baseline Rows'
                       FROM dbo.MSP_TASK_BASELINES AS TaskBase WITH(NOLOCK)
                       GROUP BY TaskBase.PROJ_UID, TaskBase.TB_BASE_NUM) AS TaskBaseData
                 GROUP BY TaskBaseData.PROJ_UID) AS TaskBaseAggregated
ON (Proj.PROJ_UID = TaskBaseAggregated.PROJ_UID)
-- Assignment Baseline Data
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT AssnBaseData.PROJ_UID
                       ,COUNT(*) AS 'Total Assn Baseline Rows'
                 FROM dbo.MSP_ASSIGNMENT_BASELINES AS AssnBaseData WITH(NOLOCK)
                 GROUP BY AssnBaseData.PROJ_UID) AS AssnBaseAggregated
ON (Proj.PROJ_UID = AssnBaseAggregated.PROJ_UID)
-- Resource Baseline Data
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT ResBaseData.PROJ_UID
                       ,COUNT(*) AS 'Total Resource Baseline Rows'
                 FROM dbo.MSP_PROJECT_RESOURCE_BASELINES AS ResBaseData WITH(NOLOCK)
                 GROUP BY ResBaseData.PROJ_UID) AS ResBaseAggregated
ON (Proj.PROJ_UID = ResBaseAggregated.PROJ_UID) 
-- Assignment Data Summary
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT AssnTaskData.PROJ_UID
                       ,AVG(AssnTaskData.[Assignment Count]) AS 'Average Resources on Assigned Tasks'
                       ,SUM(AssnTaskData.[Assignment Count]) AS 'Total Number of Assignments'
                       ,COUNT(*) AS 'Number of Tasks with Assignments'
                 FROM (SELECT Assn.PROJ_UID
                             ,Assn.TASK_UID
                             ,COUNT(*) AS 'Assignment Count'
                       FROM dbo.MSP_ASSIGNMENTS AS Assn WITH(NOLOCK)
                       GROUP BY Assn.PROJ_UID, Assn.TASK_UID) AS AssnTaskData
                 GROUP BY AssnTaskData.PROJ_UID) AS AssnDataAggregated    
 ON (Proj.PROJ_UID = AssnDataAggregated.PROJ_UID)
-- Assignment Custom Field Data
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT AssnCF.PROJ_UID
                       ,MAX(AssnCF.[Assn CF Count]) AS 'Max Assn Custom Fields'
                       ,AVG(AssnCF.[Assn CF Count]) AS 'Average Assn Custom Fields'
                       ,SUM(AssnCF.[Assn CF Count]) AS 'Total Assn Custom Fields'
                       ,COUNT(*) AS 'Number of Assn with Custom Fields'
                 FROM (SELECT ACF.PROJ_UID
                             ,ACF.ASSN_UID
                             ,COUNT(*) AS 'Assn CF Count'
                       FROM dbo.MSP_ASSN_CUSTOM_FIELD_VALUES AS ACF WITH(NOLOCK)
                       GROUP BY ACF.PROJ_UID, ACF.ASSN_UID) AS AssnCF
                 GROUP BY AssnCF.PROJ_UID) AS AssnCFAggregated
ON (Proj.PROJ_UID = AssnCFAggregated.PROJ_UID);
```